# point in rectangle test dilemma

Tags: qt, user-interface, language-agnostic, rectangles

If you check Qt's docs on the point-in-rectangle test they say:

> bool QRectF::contains(const QPointF & point) const
>
> Returns true if the given point is inside or on the edge of the
>   rectangle; otherwise returns false.

This inevitably means a point may belong to up to 4 rectangles, bordering each other, at once. Does there exist an argument in favor of this arrangement, or would it be better for the rectangle to contain only points on some edges (say, top-left)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says "edges" and not "corners". Usually edge means a line, while corner or vertex means a point.

If you want to exclude edges, `QRect` version of `contains()` can do that.

You can also write your own `contains()` and check whether the point is in the top left corner using `QRectF::topLeft()`.

Rectangles may also intersect, so a point can be contained in any number of rectangles at the same time.

Comment: Corners sit on edges. Expand your answer, please.

Comment: Do you also edges when saying "top-left"?

Comment: Yeah, say a point sits on the top or left edge exactly, then it will belong to the rectangle with the top-left convention.